gh-deploy app not working, but locally hosted does work
I’m building an Angular project that is the front end for an already function server side app that I created.  I just deployed the Angular project with gh-pages, and it isn’t working correctly -  but the app does work when I host it locally.
Not sure why this is?  The gh-page that’s hosted, doesn’t allow me to login or signup, whereas the local one does.  Also the picture background is different between the gh-page app and a local one.  Server side, I already added the gh-page url to the allowedOrigins so it’s not that.
Please help?
Github: https://github.com/chrisspenceratx/myFlix-client-Angular
hosted gh-page: https://chrisspenceratx.github.io/myFlix-client-Angular/welcome/
My app isn't working on a gh-page, but it does work when hosted locally.

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?
